# Can you use a wildcard domain callback URL for a Square Connect web application?

Tags: square-connect

I'm trying to find a way to have Square not forcefully redirect my web application on a Connect payment.  Right now, I've registered my url in https://connect.squareup.com/apps as `https://example.com/square_callback` (or whatever), and I pass along my own metadata that tell my application where to redirect back to so our users don't have to drill all the way down to where they were when they first jumped in.

So two questions.

One, is there a way to have that URI be dynamic?  They're taking payments from `https://example.com/customer/1351743`, and that's where I want them to return to, so is there a way to have a wildcard redirect uri, something like `https://example.com/customer/*`?

Second, is there a way to not have the page refresh at all?  These particular pages take a while to load, our users are out in the field with spotty connections, so while I want the square response to go to the server, I'd rather have their page not refresh at all. Possibly by using `#` in the URI?

Comment: Are you using the Point of Sale APIs, or e-commerce?

Comment: Point of Sale APIs, sorry.  Android Web, and soon iOS Web.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question, you can not register a wildcard domain or specify the the url in the request. This is mostly a security measure to prevent someone from skimming your information by hijacking your javascript. You can specify multiple urls [image: multiple redirect urls] in the developer portal and dynamically pick between them with your request.

I'm not 100% sure I understand your second question, but I'm going to interpret it as you want to switch back from the point of sale application to your webpage without "refreshing" the page. This isn't possible, since the app switch isn't as much of a switch back, as it is opening a new url. If you didn't load a new page, it wouldn't be possible to use the GET parameters that Square sends you back in the response from the transaction.

Sorry, both No :(

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping something could be done with anchor `#` hashes where it doesn't fully refresh the page, and I could manually pass that info back to my server, but I didn't know how Square was actually jumping back to the website.  I may end up doing something weird like opening a new tab right before jumping to Square so on return I can process the info and close the tab without losing the user's original place.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem, don't forget to accept the answer ;) 
If you are very concerned with poor connections, I'd look into the native Point of Sale APIs, since they can process payments online, and more elegantly handle data interrupts than a mobile  browser.